# Software to manage "application profiles", which services are running, etc., on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am looking for a particular type of program. I use my computers in various "modes", like gaming, programming, just plain surfing, etc.

What I'd like to find is a program that can help me manage these modes.

For instance, while programming I might use SQL Server, but while gaming I don't want those services running, but perhaps I'd like Steam to run instead. Basically, the program type I'm looking for is a visual program that allow me to quickly switch modes, and when I do, the program would start and stop the necessary services and applications in order to leave one mode and enter another.

I've looked at the programs related to startup management, and I haven't found one that lets me do what I want.

At the moment I have batch files, but they're not very good at conveying problems or other things, I'd like a more visual program.

Comment: +1 and favorited.  I've been looking for something like this for a while.  Good luck!

Comment: I could have sworn that "Hardware Profiles" did something similar in Windows XP, but it doesn't sound right to me...and I think they got rid of that in Vista.  Could somebody help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TuneUp Utilities has a feature they call 'Turbo Mode' that disables a few memory intensive services. Not at all worth the $40 just for that IMO, personally I keep it disabled.

Not sure what would do just what you're talking about, that's the closest I've seen to that effect.